# Won't hide content in outlook email

Tags: html, html-email

I'm trying to make a responsive email template that works with outlook. The outlook HTML works fine and the responsive HTML also works fine.

I've made use of media queries for the responsive portion, but now whenever an email is sent to Outlook the content is duplicated.

My HTML is set up as follows:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
    <style> //Media Queries are here </style>
  </head>
<body>
    <!--[if gte mso 12]>
     //All of the Outlook HTML is held here
    <![endif]--> 

    <!--[if gte mso 12]>
      <div style="width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden; display:none; 
      visibility:hidden; mso-hide:all;">
    <![endif]-->

   //All of the none Outlook HTML is held here

   <!--[if gte mso 12]></div><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to happen is that the top portion will run whenever an email is sent to outlook and if it's any other client to use the other portion of HTML.

I know this isn't the best way to do this as really I should just show and hide portions of the code instead of the whole thing, but this was easier to put together.

Interestingly this only started occurring when I started making use of media queries instead of stating the same VW for all resolutions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've tried changing the div  in the bottom portion to a table, thinking it was due to Outlook ignoring the div. All this has done was made the duplicate HTML be aligned to the left, so it's seeing the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution to this problem was to add `style="mso-hide:all"` onto every tag that was held within the second block.

Comment: There are codes for if mso and if not mso. Have you tried those? Its a much easier method.

Comment: I've tried those codes and it did originally work, but once I started making use of the media queries it stopped working for some reason.

Comment: Media queries will not break it in anyway, trust me

Comment: I eventually got time to work on this project again - Making use of the comment code <!-- if ! gte mso 12> worked to hide it in both. 

I was sure I had already tried this though and it hadn't worked. Is there any way to give you credit from a comment?

Comment: No need, am good. As long as your solution works on all devices. Be sure to check em all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `mso-hide:all` in portion you want to hide for outlook, which makes the portion hidden for Outlook specific client.